# Обращение без запятой?

Tags: пунктуация

***...Под сень его снастей //
Входи любой продрогший пилигрим...***

Почему не ставим запятую после слова ВХОДИ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ***...Под сень его снастей // Входи любой продрогший пилигрим...***
>
> Обращение без запятой?

В приведённом предложении *любой продрогший пилигрим*   — **не обращение.**

См. у [**Розенталя:**](http://www.studfiles.ru/preview/6318613/page:18/)

> Не являются обращением и не выделяются запятыми названия лица или
>   предмета, находящиеся при форме повелительного наклонения, если она
>   употреблена в значении пожелания («пусть...»)

Например:

> *Оставь надежду **всяк сюда входящий!***

.

Нет обращений и [**в этих предложениях (тоже из Розенталя):**](http://www.dolit.net/author/9403/ebook/100123/rozental_ditmar_elyashevich/punktuatsiya/read/11)

*Приходи к нему лечиться и **корова** и **волчица**.*

*Всяк **сверчок** знай свой шесток.*

*Кто **постарше** садитесь.*

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы, спасибо! )))

Answer (score 4):

По-моему, здесь нет обращения. Наверное, слово *входи* употреблено в значении *может войти*. ...Под сень его снастей // *может войти* любой продрогший пилигрим...

Answer (score 1):

А нужно бы. Не было бы "пилигрима" в конце - всё ок:

*Входи любой продрогший*...

Сравни с: *Оставь надежду, всяк сюда входящий.*

Пилигрим меняет погоду:

*Входи, любой продрогший пилигрим...*

Answer (score 0):

Да, slava1947 безусловно прав. И Розенталь прав. В общем-то это вещь известная, что не всякое упоминание адресата (пожелание, приказ, рекомендация) есть обращения.

Непонятным остается только одно. К*ак отличить этот случай от того, где обращение явно имеет место*. "Здравствуйте, Иван Иваныч!" Чем тут НЕ пожелание? Тут возникают трудности.

Видимо, надо руководствоваться возможностью замены повелительного наклонения на, так сказать, "разрешительное". Входи любой продрогший пилигрим = любой продрогший пилигрим может входить. Тогда как "Иван Иваныч может здравствовать" - это что-то совсем другое по смыслу...